# Regexp for searching letters in strings bordered by comma

Tags: regex

I have strings in db:

row 1: A,AA,ACX,AAA,AAC,ACA,ACC, CCA

row 2: A, AAX, ACC

row 3: ACA, ACCA, CCCAA, XAACC

And i need regular expression for searching count of letters bordered by comma (does not matter on letter order)

So for ex. i need: 2x A letter and 1x C letter so row 1 and 3 are satisfactory.
Or 1x A letter so row 1 and 2.

I have this: https://regex101.com/r/1Uinu0/1/ but it works only on letter A.

Comment: I think that pure regex may not be the right tool here.  In Java, I would probably split the string on comma, and then possibly use a regex after that to do some counting.

Comment: regexps can't count very well. Of course you can request a series of 77 A, but not a string that contains 77 A in total. In some simple cases an exhaustive list of patterns might work, but that'll be MANY in the general case

Answer (score 1):

regex is certainly not the more efficient tool to use, following regex matches words with exactly two A and one C:

```
(?<=^|[,\s])(?=[AC]{3}(?:[,\s]|$))(?=(?:[^A,\s]*A){2}[^A,\s]*(?:[,\s]|$))(?=(?:[^C,\s]*C){1}[^C,\s]*(?:[,\s]|$))[^,\s]*
```

may be shorten

```
(?<=^|[,\s])(?=[AC]{3}(?:[,\s]|$))(?=(?:[^A,\s]*A){2})(?=(?:[^C,\s]*C){1})[^,\s]*
```